# Twitter Auth In Android using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

I'm using firebase to authenticate with twitter, recently I'm using email to authenticate but it keeps showing me this pic [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gejoe.png) after successful authentication

but when I authenticate with username it's working fine.

Comment: I wonder if that email_disabled=true has anything to do with it? Just a thought

Comment: where is that exactly @SusanMustafa?

Comment: Look at the url.

Comment: Sorry, this picture is just for demonstration what result shows in my app, my app shows only picture.